# C-x 3 open a new buffer to the left of the current buffer

Tags: window-splitting

When strike C-x 3, a new window and buffer will open to the right of the current buffer.

How could set it open to the left of the current?

Comment: You mean you want the selected window being the one on the right?

Comment: Yes, I want my focus window on right and the new opened window to its left. @JeanPierre

Comment: Here is an example of how to display a buffer in any one of four directions, i.e., above, below, left, and right:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50867710/2112489

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`C-x 3` is bound to the function `split-window-right`, that splits the current window horizontally, selecting the left window.  We can define a function `split-window-left` that calls it then change the selected window to the one on the right, eg using `other window`:

> other-window is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘window.el’.
>
> (other-window COUNT &optional ALL-FRAMES)
>
> Select another window in cyclic ordering of windows.
>   COUNT specifies the number of windows to skip, starting with the
>   selected window, before making the selection.

```el
(defun split-window-left (&optional size)
  "Like split-window-right, with selected window on the right."
  (interactive "P")
  (split-window-right size)
  (other-window 1))
```

We keep the same semantics for the optional`size` argument: give the width of the left window if positive, of the right one if negative.

You can bind this to `C-x 3` (overriding the binding to `split-window-right`) or to another key, eg `C-x 9`:

```
(global-set-key  "\C-x9" 'split-window-left)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick, and it's built in:

(split-window-right-and-focus)

Split the window horizontally and focus the new window.

Comment: Unfortunately this function does not take a SIZE parameter.

Comment: Can't find this function.  Where is it defined? (I'm using emacs 26.1 so it may be too old...)

Comment: keybindings.el.  I'm on Emacs 27.2 so maybe it's a newer function?

Comment: Oops!  I was looking through the source code, and this is part of Spacemacs!  My fault @JeanPierre.